# Minimizing SSD in Python with observation level constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to minimize the sum of squared difference between a vector of weights (which sum to 1), w and a new vector, z = a*w, given constraints on each value such that y1 <= z <= y2.

I'm used to minimization problems with a constraint for each variable, not varying constraints for each variable.

Is there an obvious solution I am missing?  Below is a toy example, the real problem has about 215 observations.

```
w = np.array[0.01795054, 0.05355763, 0.16370357, 0.01856683, 0.05610746,
       0.05578166, 0.17662216, 0.32852952, 0.08550193, 0.04367869]

y2 = np.array[0.0856799 , 0.04886273, 0.16629066, 0.0598285 , 0.12070527,
       0.14514881, 0.17162558, 0.17162558, 0.15048137, 0.13325034]

y1 = np.array[0.01243839, 0.00860495, 0.01947604, 0.01355602, 0.0039714 ,
       0.00853402, 0.00686692, 0.01595278, 0.01759997, 0.01807684]
```

Comment: The way I think about it, I need to min (aw - w)^2 subject to aw >= y1 and aw <= y2. But a is a vector, not a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which part you are struggling with, but you basically only need to write down the optimization problem in the comments and solve it with [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Note that the constraint y1 <= a*w <= y2 is equivalent to the two constraints y2 - a*w >= 0 and -y1 + a*w >= 0:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(a):
    return np.sum((a*w - w)**2)

# constraints
constrs = [
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda a:  y2 - a*w},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda a: -y1 + a*w}
]

# initial guess
x0 = np.ones(w.size)

# solve the problem: res.x contains your solution
res = minimize(objective, constraints=constrs, x0=x0)
```